# Change Textmate Bookmark Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

How do I change the Textmate bookmark shortcuts?

The default Textmate navigate bookmark shortcuts are <kbd>F2</kbd> / <kbd>⇧ + F2</kbd>. This is not very convenient for me, because on my Mac the function keys are set to be system commands, eg <kbd>F2</kbd> is increase brightness. I would rather map to <kbd>⌥ + ⌘ + ↑</kbd> / <kbd>⌥ + ⌘ + ↓</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps under "16.2 Menu Items" in the [online docs](http://manual.macromates.com/en/key_bindings).

Note: if you wish to use the shortcuts I specified above, they collide with the Ruby on Rails bundle so you will need to update it also.